# Using jQuery UI in Symfony2 through Composer. How do I publish assets from vendors directory?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, symfony, composer-php

In a Symfony 2.3 project I want to install jQuery UI using Composer. I found the package `components/jqueryui` available on packagist.com

The project is also using [BraincraftedBootstrapBundle](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/) that loads jQuery (see [Getting Started](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html)).

I have 2 problems with this configuration:

1. I have no idea how to access in my Twig tempaltes the jQuery UI files that are located in `vendors/components/jqueryui`.
2. How can I tell Composer that I don't want jQuery UI to require it's dependency `components/jquery`, since jQuery library is already installed by BraincraftedBootstrapBundle, under `jquery/jquery` or to tell BraincraftedBootstrapBundle to use jQuery from `components/jquery`.

Running `composer show -i | grep jquery` brings up this:

```
components/jquery     2.1.3    jQuery JavaScript Library
components/jqueryui   1.11.4   jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library. W...
jquery/jquery         1.11.2
```

Comment: OK, I've just found how I can tell BraincraftedBootstrapBundle to use jQuery from `components/jquery` package. Added `braincrafted_bootstrap.jquery_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js` in `config.yml`.

Comment: did you find a way to user properly jquery-ui from vendors so that image url in css are correct? I managed to configure assetic to dump css file to web but I cannot find a way to dump images folder.

Comment: I've created symlinks for each and every image from `/vendor/components/jqueryui/themes/base/images/[image_name]` to `/web/images/[image_name]`. It's more like a hack than a solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. you can define the vendor path for the file in your `config.yml`.
   files stay in the vendor folder.
2. you can also define a `components-dir` (custom config directive for "components"):

   ```
   {
       "require": {
           "components/jquery":     "^2.0",
           "components/jqueryui":   "^1.11"
       },
       "config": {
           "component-dir": "web/assets"
       }
    }
   ```
3. or you can trigger a custom install command and move the asset files from the vendor folder to your assets folder and then define this asset path.
4. or you can use `bower`, executed as a postinstall command, to fetch and install the assets into a defined dir. https://github.com/bower/bower/tree/v0.3.0#bower-configuration

Comment: Thank you! I already found and tested the first method, added named assets in `config.yml` under `assetic.assets` and it works. The only issue I'm having now is that jQuery UI images (datepicker) are missing. Symfony expects them to be located in `web/images` folder and the `cssrewrite` filter seems to misbehave a bit here. Your answer is good but it's lacking details.

Comment: Maybe this post helps you to fix the image loading issue: http://afriyadilim.blogspot.de/2011/08/symfony-2-assetic-with-jqueryui.html